# Вернуть load у которых один и тот же sku но разный lot в одной location

Tags: sql, oracle

Подскажите, как реализовать запрос?
Есть таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо вывести только те `load`, у которых один и тот же `sku` но разный `lot` в одной `location`
Т.е. запрос должен вернуть только `load2` и `load3`.

Вроде и не сложный запрос, но мозг мне сломал.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю можна сделать так:

```
select * from table1 as tt
inner join 
(select t.sku, t.location from table1 as t 
group by t.sku, t.location 
having count(distinct t.lot)>1)  as t1
on tt.sku=t1.sku and tt.location=t1.location
```

Comment: Так он возвращает и `load1`

Comment: select * from table1 as tt
inner join 
 
(select t.sku, t.location from table1 as t 
group by t.sku, t.location 
having count(distinct t.lot)>1)  as t1
on tt.sku=t1.sku and tt.location=t1.location

Answer (score 0):

Решил следующим образом:

```
select load 
from table
where exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.load != table.load and t1.sku = table.sku 
and t1.location = table.location and t1.lot != table.lot);
```